# Make chatbot start conversation on GET-request in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

is there anyone out there who knows if it is possible to make your agent start a conversation with user without any code using Dialogflow(api.ai)?

Comment: What chat platform are you using with Dialogflow? the Google Assistant integration does this already

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following this tutorial : https://miningbusinessdata.com/get-api-ai-agent-initiate-conversation-user-types-message/

Also some channels like messenger allow you to set a welcome message to initiate the conversation. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button/)